# Proving that a multi-variable function is concave

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Consider the following multi-variable function with $a_i, b_i, c_i, x_i > 0$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sqrt{b_i + \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \frac{x_j}{\sum_k c_k x_k} }
\end{align}

Can we show that this function is concave? Eigenvalues of $x \sqrt{\frac{y}{(x+y)+1}} + y \sqrt{\frac{x}{(x+y)+1}}$, which is a special case, are nonpositive. Can we somehow use an inductive argument to show the above is concave?

Comment: Write your function as $\sum x_i \sqrt{b_i + \frac{a^\intercal x}{c^\intercal x}}.$ Now use operations that preserve concavity, for example, $t \mapsto \frac{1}{t}$ ($t > 0$) changes concavity for convexity and vice versa. Conclude that each of $b_i + \frac{a^\intercal x}{b^\intercal x}$ is concave and since $t \mapsto \sqrt{t}$ is concave increase, so is their square root, and finally sum of concave is concave. (I didn't check any step but this is the way to go it seems.)